# Travel with an 3 years old children in Disneyland Paris

Tags: children, family, disney

Our godparents want to travel this year in West Europe with their little girl. They will only have 5-6 days to enjoy a perfect vacation. Me and my husband think that Disneyland Paris would be a great choice because it could be fun for all of them (we've been there last year and we liked it verry much).

Is Disneyland suitable for a 3 years old kid?

Comment: That's very broad, you would need to tell us where you are coming from, for how long, etc. to make this even remotely answerable. But the question is probably going to be closed as “opinion-based” anyway, even if you narrow it down so I am not sure it's worth the trouble. Maybe the chat would be a better place to discuss this?

Comment: Maerchenstrasse? Reichenbach Falls? Aquapark Oberhausen? The Avignon Palmeraie? I took my 5 yo to those places with great results. Nobody knows what's right for you.  Europe is large (for us anyway) and we can't support opinion polls because the site philosophy is there's a single precise answer for each question.  So I'm voting to close this question as opinion-based, please think up a more 'focused' question.

Comment: Where do you come from? What else has the child seen? Even if he or she is only five years old, you should select some distinctly *european* landmarks. Go to Rome, look at the Colosseum. Or go to London, look at Big Ben. Or go to Oslo, look at the Viking Ship Museum.

Comment: And now the question has changed considerably...